# How to submit two models to an action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im stuck with a problem on a view that I need to make.

Theres an home/index page with a custom search button.

**First case** *Registered User* -  after the user clicks to make the search, it redirect to a `GET` `Payment/Index` view with a partial view rendered within its **UserData** and another partial view with the `Payment form` that user will fill with its bank data to make the payment for the search.

**Second case** *New User* -  after the user clicks it, it redirect to a `GET` Payment/IndexNewUser view with a partial view rendered  within a `NewUser form` to create an account and a `Payment PartialView` with the `Payment form` that user will fill with its bank data to make the payment for the search. Both forms in the same submit button.

In the second case i need to register and authenticate the user before and make the payment after.

I thought in these options:

1) Make a `ActionResult RegisteredUserPay(Payment model)` and other `ActionResult NewUerPay(NewUserPayment model)` both in the `Payment Controller` and in the second  Action make two things, register the user and make the payment.

2) Stay with the `ActionResult Pay(Payment model)` on the `PaymentController` and when a new user submit, send the post to a `ActionResult CreateUser(RegisterViewModel model)` on the `UserController` and then make a `RedirectToAction("Pay","Payment", model.Payment)`.

Both cases are strange in the architecture point of view, because in the 1st option the PaymentController will be responsable to register a user. And in the other case i will need to create two Views that are basically the same, but for different models.

How is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making it too complicated. All you need is a view model like:

```
public class SearchPayViewModel
{
    public RegisterViewModel Register { get; set; }
    public Payment Payment { get; set; }
}
```

You only need one action and one view. Inside your view, simply branch on whether the user is authenticated and only render the register partial, if not:

```
@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Register", model.Register)
}
```

On post, `model.Register` will be null if nothing was posted, and obviously if the register partial was not rendered, nothing will be posted. As a result, you can then do a simple check to see if you need to create the user or not:

```
if (model.Register != null)
{
    // create user
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this way i think i cannot trust in the ModelState.IsValid. And it should not work. The Model of the _Register partialview should be the same of the index view becouse both are in the same submit form, the model.Register will send null always to the action.

Comment: Validation is only run on an instance if it's not null, so you're fine there. If it's not posted, just the payment fields will be validated. I have no idea what the rest of your comment is about. However, please try this before dismissing it out of hand. I've done things like this many times before and I can assure you this will work just fine.

Comment: Sorry i dont mean to dismissing it, i will try and see what will happen. Thank you.